# Como crear un programa que pida al usuario que teclee cuatro palabras y las muestre en pantalla creando una oración

Tags: c

En lenguaje C, tiene que salir entre comillas, y no tiene ajuro que tener sentido la oracion,  soy nuevo en esto y necesito completar esto para hoy y lo he intentado varias veces y no me sale. llevo esto

```
    printf("Introduce la primera palabra ");
    scanf("%s", &a);

    printf("Introduce la segunda palabra ");
    scanf("%s", &b);

    printf("Introduce la tercera palabra ");
    scanf("%s", &c);

    printf("Introduce la cuarta palabra ");
    scanf("%s", &d);

    printf("a,b,c,d);
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Agrega tus intentos fallidos, para poder ayudarte. Puedes hacer clic en [edit]. Una sugerencia: el código agrégalo en formato texto (copiar y pegar). Saludos

Comment: Siempre será mejor revisar tus intentos fallidos y encontrar el fallo, que decir _soy nuevo_ y simplemente recibir las cosas hechas. Además, así no funciona el sitio. Ánimo, edita tu pregunta para que recibas respuesta pronto

Comment: Súper! Gracias por editar tu pregunta. QUé error te sale? ese es el main? Puedes añadir esa información a la pregunta también.

Comment: Inicia con int main()

Comment: Y despues abajo char a,b,c,d;

Answer (score 1):

En C, printf funciona poniendo las variables fuera de las comillas, y dentro de los comillas va el formato del texto

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char a[50];
    char b[50];
    char c[50];
    char d[50];
    
    printf("Introduce la primera palabra: ");
    scanf("%s", a);

    printf("Introduce la segunda palabra: ");
    scanf("%s", b);

    printf("Introduce la tercera palabra: ");
    scanf("%s", c);

    printf("Introduce la cuarta palabra: ");
    scanf("%s", d);

    printf("La frase es: %s %s %s %s", a,b,c,d);
 
    return 0;
}
```